# How to print all elements in a 2D map given the 1st index

Tags: c++

As the title says I want to print out all the elements of "group1" in this 2D map. I tried this but I just get a huge error at the for loop.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  map<string,map<int,double> > myMap;
  myMap["group1"][13] = 10.41;
  myMap["group1"][15] = 31.2;

  //print all elements in "group1"
  for (map< string, map<int,double> >::const_iterator iter = 
       myMap["group1"].begin(); iter != myMap["group1"].end(); ++iter)
       {
         cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second << '\n';
       }

  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: and the error message is?

Comment: and what version of c++

Comment: Auto x = myMap["group1"]; for(auto y : x) cout << y.first << y.second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `myMap["group1"]` is `map<int,double>` and not `map<string,map<int,double>>`

Then your code would look somehow like this:

```
const map<int,double> &grp1map = myMap["group1"];
for (map<int,double>::const_iterator iter = grp1map.begin(); iter != grp1map.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second << '\n';
}
```

You can simplify this with `auto`:

```
auto &grp1map = myMap["group1"];
for (auto iter = grp1map.begin(); iter != grp1map.end(); ++iter) 
{
    cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second << '\n';
}
```

But anyway you should do it like this:

```
for (auto &elem : myMap["group1"] )
{
    cout << elem.first << '\t' << elem.second << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Auto's are your friend they help with this convoluted iterator syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You want an iterator to your internal `map<int,double>`, whereas you are trying to get and iterator to your outer `map<string,map<int,double> >`:

```
int main() {
    map<string, map<int, double> > myMap;
    myMap["group1"][13] = 10.41;
    myMap["group1"][15] = 31.2;

    //print all elements in "group1"
    for (map<int, double>::const_iterator iter =
        myMap["group1"].begin(); iter != myMap["group1"].end(); ++iter)
    {
        cout << iter->first << '\t' << iter->second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```